# Creating Multiple Related Rows in One Operation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a class Document and a class Home. I also have made a relation Document_Home.

What I want to do is to select some photos and create them as Documents once the button "Create Home" is pressed.

How should I do this?

Document has its own controller with a create method and the same for Home and Document_Home.

Is there something like a transaction?

First, create the Home.
Second, create the Documents
Third, create the relation between Documents and Home.

Comment: You would want to create a separate controller that uses both models or just add one of the models to the other's controller.  I don't think it matters - but it would probably be more "MVC" to create a separate controller for whatever type of operation this is.

Comment: Think somebody has to evaluate that so I'd prefer to do it as "puritan" as possible :)

Comment: What database access technology are you using? Entity Framework?

Comment: It's good to have such things in the tags

Comment: What I really want to know is how to deal with relations in mvc. I can create the tables, the models, the controllers, the views for each one but, how do I create now one view which allows me to create everything with one button?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to my previous comment, you may want to consider using a "repository pattern."  You don't need any DB context for this, I just mean create a project in your solution adjacent to your MVC project called "Repositories" and then create a new class that has functionality like this:

```
public class MyCustomRepo
{
    public void MyCreateMethod(List<MyPhotoObject> photos)
    {
        foreach (var photo in photos)
        {
            // create home
            // create documents
            // create relation
        }
    }
}
```

This would keep your number of controllers down and would be "SOC" separation of concerns being as this is more data layer than logic layer.  I think it would keep your code a lot cleaner.

You'll have to reference the DLL from your repositories project in your MVC project.

Comment: I like that... create home should be before the foreach line. And how can I "rollback" this if some step fails???

Comment: If you are using an ORM like Entity Framework you can use `myContext.SaveChanges()` when you know everything is OK.  Otherwise, you can try using `TransactionScope` like http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1326ef/transactionscope-in-C-Sharp/